# Ctrl-Z deletes texture when texture painting

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Does anyone have a solution to this? Sometimes when I Ctrl-Z when texture painting and I haven't saved my textures to a PNG yet, it deletes the whole thing. Which makes me have to start over again. It's happened a lot the last few days, I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Ctrl Z doesn't always work as we expect, maybe report it to Blender developers so that it changes?

Comment: yeah this is also a thing when im weight paining with a mask. it removes the weight and the mask instead of just the weight. hopefully blender fixes this

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/110840